# call generic handler in aspx without jquery

Tags: javascript

Can i call Generic handler in aspx without using jQuery?

Comment: @Paul Alexander: can you please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, jQuery itself is a javascript, so you can call by writing your own script. The benefit of using jQuery is you don't need to worry about browser compatability, have to write less code, can get advantage of using jquery plugins etc, only the cost of adding jQuery.js.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Intialize XMLHTTP object
    function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var A;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            A = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            var msxmlhttp = new Array(
        'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0',
        'Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
        'Msxml2.XMLHTTP',
        'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            for (var i = 0; i < msxmlhttp.length; i++) {
                try {
                    A = new ActiveXObject(msxmlhttp[i]);
                    break;
                } catch (e) {
                    A = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return A;
    }


    function sendAjaxRequest(url, postVars, callbackFunc) {
        var isPost = (postVars && postVars.length > 0);

        var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }


        if (!isPost) {
            if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                url += '?' + uncache();
            } else {
                url += '&' + uncache();
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { //This function will execute on receive
                var callback;
                var extra_data = false;

                var data = xmlHttp.responseText;

                callback = callbackFunc;
                callbackFunc(data, extra_data);
            }
        };        

        //Send data to the url through ajax
        if (isPost) {
            xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", postVars.length);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlHttp.send(postVars);
        } else {
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
    }

    function uncache() {
        var d = new Date();
        var time = d.getTime();

        return 'time=' + time;
    }

    function comp(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    sendAjaxRequest('test.html', '', comp);


</script>
```